# Center-set column headers in siunitx S columns

Tags: tables, siunitx

I'm using the `siunitx` package to automatically put thousand separators in all my `tabular` environments.

It works fine, but not if you have a column header. This seemingly innocuous MWE fails to compile with an utterly bizarre error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx} 
% Adds the S column for formatting numbers like 10,000

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llSS}
&     & Trade Value &  Estimation Error \\
&     & (\$US M) &  (\$US M) \\
USA & GBR &    15574 & -5753 \\
GBR & USA &    15668 & -4127 \\
USA & JPN &     4261 &  3092 \\
GBR & LUX &     1590 &  2766 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I've gleaned from questions like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238515/centering-column-headers-in-siunitx-table-column) that the answer is to do `multicolumn{1}{c}{My Header}`.

This seems like a bore, given all my tables have headers.

The alternatives all seem to involve putting every number into an environment like `\num`. This is clearly no solution at all, if your tables are large.

Is there a package which will put thousand separators into my `tabulars` without the need for either the `multicolumn` headers or the `\num{}` around every number in the table?

Comment: You could use regex in your favorite text editor to ease the pain to create braces around the terms. Also, you do not have to use `S`-columns all the time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Centering the material in the header cells of a column of type `S` may be achieved easily by encasing the material in curly braces. For sure, typing `{...}` is a lot quicker than `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` is, right?

In order to properly center the numeric material in columns three and four, you may want to replace the basic `S` declarations with `S[table-format=5.0]` and `S[table-format=-4.0]`, respectively. Finally, I'd add the option `group-minimum-digits=4` so that the use of `,` as the thousands-separator applies to *all* numbers in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-separator={,},
            group-minimum-digits = 4]  % default is 5
            {siunitx} % Adds the S column type

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll S[table-format=5.0] S[table-format=-4.0]}
&     & {Trade Value} &  {Estimation Error} \\
&     & {(\$US M)} &  {(\$US M)} \\[1ex]
USA & GBR &    15574 & -5753 \\
GBR & USA &    15668 & -4127 \\
USA & JPN &     4261 &  3092 \\
GBR & LUX &     1590 &  2766 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know it's a *faux pas* to put a thank you in the comments, but this really is the best answer imaginable. Does exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: @LondonRob - You're welcome! (The *faux pas*, if any, would be to leave verbal praise while not upvoting the answer...)